# Deny running scripts in nginx for specific url

Tags: nginx, config, run-script

I have a media folder on URL `example.com/media/` and I want to deny users running scripts in my server. My server app is nginx and in [How to deny script execution inside writable directories](http://www.nginxtips.com/how-to-deny-script-execution-inside-writable-directories/) I couldn't find anything special about specific URL. This is my nginx server config:

```
# sites-avalaible/default
server {
        listen  80;
        listen  443 ssl;
        server_name     www.example.com example.com;
        ssl_certificate /var/www/example/ssl/ssl.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key     /var/www/example/ssl/ssl.key;
        location /static  {
                alias   /var/www/example/static;
                expires 7d;
                add_header Pragma public;
                add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";

        }
        location /media  {
                alias  /var/www/example/media;
                # limit download speed after 5mb download
                limit_rate_after 5m;
                limit_rate 120k;
                limit_req zone=lh burst=5 nodelay;
        }
        location / {
                proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        }
}
```

I want to deny running any executable stuff in my media URL in which users can upload their files to server. How can I do that? For example when user navigates to `example.com/media/bomb.py` nginx return 404 error page. I've also changed media folder executing permissions but I need to do it for nginx in order to stop viewing script files.

Comment: Your current configuration already do not allow script execution in media directory. You don't need to do anything

Answer (score 3):

This will disable all php and py script execution inside media directory. Like this you can disable any other script.

```
 location /media/ { 
    location ~ .*\.(php)?$ 
    { 
      deny all; 
    } 
    location ~ .*\.(py)?$ 
    { 
      deny all; 
    }
 }
```

Comment: Good example of wrapping a regex location with a prefix location. This will allow the config to scale without blocking other regex locations.

Comment: How do I reverse it, so allow only jpg|png|gif and deny everything else?

Comment: location ~* \.(jpg|png|gif) {
}
location  / {
    deny all; 
}

Answer (score 1):

Edit: If support for other script types are added later, it would be safer to only serve recognized media types and deny the rest:

```
location ^~ /media/ {
    location ~ \.(?:jpg|png|gif)$ {}
    return 403; # or 404
}
```

Comment: How do I reverse it, so allow only `jpg|png|gif` and deny everything else?

Comment: Try this: `location /media/ {location ~ ^/media/.*\.(?:jpg|png|gif)$ {} return 403;}`

Comment: Even better: `location ^~ /media/ {location ~ ^/media/.*\.(?:jpg|png|gif)$ {} return 403;}`

Comment: One more: `location ^~ /media/ {location ~ \.(?:jpg|png|gif)$ {} return 403;}`

Comment: I'm glad you asked! It's a better way to approach the problem.

Comment: Any chance you can help with this: http://serverfault.com/questions/799298/rewrite-rule-for-nginx-opencart ? I have the regex, just can't get it right.

Answer (score -2):

### Location for media to prevent execution of php

location ^~ /media/              {}